# Why use WAS-CE over Apache Geronimo?

Tags: apache, websphere, geronimo

What benefits do I gain by using IBM WebSphere Application Server Community Edition over Apache Geronimo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember from some of IBM's demos, there are not much differences between WAS CE's and Geronimo codebases. Altough there was some WAS CE specific development in the past, components developed specificaly for WAS CE were adopted by the Geronimo project.

The main WAS CE benefits I see are:

- Documentation for WAS CE at IBM's Infocenter. Other IBM's middlewares are documented fairly well there, so to me, this really would be a benefit.
- IBM provides support for WAS CE the same way it does for other IBM products
- Migration from CE to other Websphere products is supported.
- More OSs are supported (well, not a big benefit, but it could make the installation easier in some cases).
- Derby DB embedded (again, at least it somewhat simplifies installation)

If you plan to move to other Websphere AS in the future, then WAS CE is certainly a better choice. Also note there is a difference in licensing of both appservers - WAS CE uses an IBM licence, not the Apache one.